# MS Excel Forumla assistance

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell I need to split into 2 cells.

Data Sample:  *Note: All Cells are formatted as TEXT*

1. "3851v61_18.005_ Have the anchors for all suspended scaffolding system suspension lines and separate vertical lifelines been verified? "
2. Data Sample 2:  Parent_ID

Steps:

1. Need to check to see  if the cell value starts with number.
2. Also, If it contains a special character ("_") if may have more than 1.
3. Display cell #1 = just the ID number containing the underscore(s).
4. Display cell #2 - Just the text right of the underscore.  However, if the original cell only starts with Alpha characters then display the actual value. ie.  Parent_Id
5. Strip off any erroneous underscores left hanging.

Expected results:
Cell #:

1. "3851v61_18.005" (ID Number portion of the Text)
2. "Have the anchors for all suspended scaffolding system suspension lines and separate vertical lifelines been verified?

This is what I have so far:  *(If it does not start with a number, then return the value of the cell, else continue with the equation)*

```
`=`IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(C321,1))>=1,IFERROR(LEFT(C321, FIND("_",C321)-1), C321),FALSE)` 


=IFERROR(RIGHT(C321,LEN(C321)-FIND("_",C321)), C321)`
```

If the Underscore count is more than one need to include it in the entire number and strip off the text after the last underscore in Cell 1. At the same for the right of the Underscore to display the text after underscore in Cell 2.

Thank you for any assistances offered.

Comment: Your explanation and sample data is not clear-- where are you getting "EXTERNAL_UUIID OR" or "in_co_uuid" in results 4 and 5? Also, in your description, you say "3... just the whole number contained within the underscore", but then for your sample data you show "3851v23_12.001_Comments" yielding "3851v23-12.001" rather than "12". Can you improve your explanation and sample data/results so we can better help you?

Comment: However, I do have some cells that may not contain any of the ID numbers only text that may have contain an underscore.

Here is a better example of the data that may be contained in the cell:

"3851v61_18.005_ Have the anchors for all suspended scaffolding system suspension lines and separate vertical lifelines been verified? "

So the results should be:

Cell 1 ="3851v61_18.005"
Cell 2 = "Have the anchors for all suspended scaffolding system suspension lines and separate vertical lifelines been verified? "

Comment: Sorry I wasn't Clear  I am attempting to strip out data from 1 cell into 2 different cells:  there are no Whole Numbers it is all Text.  See above post for a clearer data sample.  also not all cells include the ID number, it could contain Text that may include an underscore (ie. the Parent_ID samples)

Comment: Please put ALL the logic and the data sample into your question. Nobody wants to read through a wall of comments to understand what you're really asking. You can edit your question at any time to provide more detail.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. *MS Excel* is clearly mentioned by the tag you added, and *assistance* is what every question posted here needs, so your title contains zero useful information. Your title should be descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem, and your title as written provides nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand but am not 100% sure.

Try something like the below to get the full string (if it starts with something that isn't a number) or the string up to the last underscore (if it does start with a number):

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT($D1,1)))), $D1,
LEFT($D1, FIND("!!!", SUBSTITUTE($D1, "_", "!!!",
LEN($D1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D1, "_", ""))))-1))
```

Then in a similar fashion try something like the below to get the full string (if it starts with something that isn't a number) or the string to right of the last underscore (if it does start with a number):

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT($D1,1)))), $D1,
RIGHT($D1, LEN($D1)-FIND("!!!", SUBSTITUTE($D1, "_", "!!!",
LEN($D1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D1, "_", ""))))))
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work, it is almost there.  It is not handling the if there is a second underscore in the ID number. It is still leaving a portion of the id in with the text in some cases.  I believe it is due to when there are more than 1 underscore.  ie. "3813v6_2.008_Are all employees trained:

Comment: What is wrong with the return in the picture above? It seems to return the correct text even when there are multiple underscores (e.g. "18_3_243_does this work" splits into "18_3_243" and "does this work")

Comment: thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: No problem, if you found it answered your question, consider marking it as accepted (the check mark next to the answer)